# Sending data remotely from iPhone native apps to Rails apps

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objective-c, json

I have decided to develop a native iPhone apps as a compliment to our webapps. Now I am wondering what are my options to send data remotely from the iPhone apps - since the database is online - to our online database. What I can think of on top of my head - since I come from web dev background - is JSON. My webapps is built using Rails, so I figure it would not be difficult to accept JSON request from the iPhone apps. But the next question is, is it difficult to send JSON data remotely from the iPhone apps? If JSON is not recommendable, what are my other options?

Thank you so much for the assistance. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using this lib: http://iphoneonrails.com/

Comment: Will my application still be a native iphone apps? Because I still want the apps to be distributed at Apple app store.

Answer (score 0):

See [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for an Objective-C framework for packing and unpacking JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at http://github.com/jeena/plistifier it uses binary plists so you don't have to parse them on the iPhone on your own and they are 1/10 of the size of XML.